# Create a List of hours

Tags: c#, time, datetime-format

I'm trying to create list of hours my code like

```
 var hours = Enumerable.Range(00, 24).Select(i => i.ToString("D2")));
```

it generates something like this in 24 hour format 
but actually i need same thing not on 24 hours but 12 like after with AM PM postfix

what is the best way to generate hour list with `00.00 AM/PM` formatted

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var hours = Enumerable.Range(00, 24).Select(i => (DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(i)).ToString("hh.mm tt"));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `DateTime` instance then use `ToString` format of `hh.mm tt`.

```
var hours = Enumerable.Range(00, 24)
    .Select(i => new DateTime(2000,1,1,i,0,0).ToString("hh.mm tt"));
```

You need to execute the query using something like `ToArray()` to get the result since the behavior of linq is deferred execution.

Answer (score 3):

You're dealing with time, so using appropriate type, `DateTime`, seems better than using `int`:

```
var hours = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
            let h = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, i, 0, 0)
            select h.ToString("t", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today;
IEnumerable<DateTime> listOfHours = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(h => startDate.AddHours(h));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more flexibility and have from/to for specific times that overlap midnight (and increase step to let's say every 2h) you can use something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetListOfHours(DateTime start, DateTime end, int step)
{
    while (start <= end)
    {
        yield return start.ToString("hh.mm tt");
        start = start.AddHours(step);
    }
}
```

So this:

```
var start = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(6); // 6 am
var end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.AddHours(2); // 2 am
var step = 1;

var list = GetListOfHours(start, end, step);
```

Will produce this:

```
06.00 AM
07.00 AM
08.00 AM
09.00 AM
10.00 AM
11.00 AM
12.00 PM
01.00 PM
02.00 PM
03.00 PM
04.00 PM
05.00 PM
06.00 PM
07.00 PM
08.00 PM
09.00 PM
10.00 PM
11.00 PM
12.00 AM
01.00 AM
02.00 AM
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8LYxA6